# Вставка картинки в JTextPane после копирования

Tags: java

Когда я копирую картинку в папку с ресурсами и пытаюсь ее вставить, тогда `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(nameFile);` 
принимает значение `null`, при этом копирование файла проходит успешно. Если же перезагрузить программу и выбрать туже картинку тогда все будет работать. В чем может быть проблема?

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    /*
                     *       Выбор картинки
                     */

                    FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog((Frame)null, "Виберіть картинку");
                    dialog.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                    File file = new File(dialog.getDirectory() + dialog.getFile());

                    /*
                     *       Копирование изображение в папку с рисурсами
                     */

                    try {
                        String fileName = new File(new File("").getAbsoluteFile() + "\\src\\main\\resources\\" + dialog.getFile()).toString();
                        if (!(new File(fileName)).exists()) {
                            copyFileUsingJava7Files(file, new File(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile() + "\\src\\main\\resources\\" + dialog.getFile()));
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    /*
                    *       Вставка изображение в конец текста JTextPane
                    */

                    URL imgUrl= getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(dialog.getFile());
                    HTMLDocument doc=(HTMLDocument) textPane.getStyledDocument();
                    try {
                        System.out.println(imgUrl);
                        doc.insertAfterEnd(doc.getCharacterElement(doc.getLength()),"<img src=\""
                                + imgUrl
                                + "\">");
                    } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в URL, без понятия почему. Вообщем сделал новый URL и все заработало`URL imgUrl = file.toURL();`